# Posterior collapses in an RNN variational auto-encoder - PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to implement and train an RNN variational auto-encoder as the one explained in "[Generating Sentences from a Continuous Space](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06349)". Although I apply their proposed techniques to mitigate posterior collapse (or at least I think I do), my model's posterior collapses.

I will provide my model implementation in PyTorch, then my training loop.
Looking forward to your feedback.

Some snippets are borrowed from [this github repo](https://github.com/timbmg/Sentence-VAE).

My imports

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn.utils.rnn as rnn_utils
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.nn.utils import clip_grad_norm_
import torch.nn.utils.weight_norm as weightNorm

import torchtext
from torchtext.vocab import GloVe
import numpy as np
import time
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
```

My model

```
class RVAE(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, vsz, edim, hdim, dropout, zdim, nlayers, bi_enc,
                 sos_idx, eos_idx, pad_idx, unk_idx, vocab, pretrained_vectors, device):

        super().__init__()
        self.device = device
        self.vocab = vocab

        self.sos_idx = sos_idx
        self.eos_idx = eos_idx
        self.pad_idx = pad_idx
        self.unk_idx = unk_idx
        self.vsz = vsz

        self.zdim = zdim

        self.bi_enc = bi_enc
        self.nlayers = nlayers
        self.hdim = hdim

        self.enc_emb = nn.Embedding(vsz, edim, padding_idx=pad_idx).from_pretrained(pretrained_vectors)
        self.dec_emb = nn.Embedding(vsz, edim, padding_idx=pad_idx).from_pretrained(pretrained_vectors)
        self.dropout = dropout

        self.enc_rnn = nn.LSTM(edim, hdim, num_layers=nlayers, bidirectional=bi_enc, batch_first=True,
                               dropout=dropout)
        self.ndirections = 2 if bi_enc else 1
        self.dec_rnn = nn.LSTM(edim+zdim, self.ndirections*hdim, num_layers=nlayers, bidirectional=False,
                               batch_first=True, dropout=dropout)

        self.h_factor = (self.ndirections) * nlayers

        self.hidden_transformation = nn.Linear(hdim * self.h_factor, hdim * self.h_factor)
        self.hidden2mean = nn.Linear(hdim * self.h_factor, zdim)
        self.hidden2logv = nn.Linear(hdim * self.h_factor, zdim)
        self.latent2hidden = nn.Linear(zdim, hdim * self.h_factor)
        self.outlayer = nn.Linear(hdim * self.ndirections, vsz)

        self.init_weights()
        self.to(device)

    def init_weights(self, initrange=0.1):
        self.enc_emb.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        self.dec_emb.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)

        self.hidden_transformation.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        self.hidden_transformation.bias.data.zero_()

        self.hidden2mean.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        self.hidden2mean.bias.data.zero_()

        self.hidden2logv.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        self.hidden2logv.bias.data.zero_()

        self.latent2hidden.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        self.latent2hidden.bias.data.zero_()

        self.outlayer.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        self.outlayer.bias.data.zero_()
        # taken from https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/initializing-rnn-gru-and-lstm-correctly/23605/2
        for name, param in self.enc_rnn.named_parameters():
            if 'weight_ih' in name:
                torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(param.data)
            elif 'weight_hh' in name:
                torch.nn.init.orthogonal_(param.data)
            elif 'bias' in name:
                param.data.zero_()

        for name, param in self.dec_rnn.named_parameters():
            if 'weight_ih' in name:
                torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(param.data)
            elif 'weight_hh' in name:
                torch.nn.init.orthogonal_(param.data)
            elif 'bias' in name:
                param.data.zero_()

    def encode(self, inp):
        bsz, seqlen = inp.size()
        # ENCODER
        inp_emb = F.dropout(self.enc_emb(inp), p=self.dropout)
        _, enc_h = self.enc_rnn(inp_emb)

        if self.bi_enc or self.nlayers > 1:
            # flatten hidden state
            hidden = enc_h[0].view(bsz, self.hdim*self.h_factor)
        else:
            hidden = hidden[0].squeeze()

        hidden = F.dropout(F.elu(self.hidden_transformation(F.dropout(hidden, p=self.dropout))), p=self.dropout)
        # REPARAMETERIZATION
        mean = self.hidden2mean(hidden)
        logv = self.hidden2logv(hidden)
        std = torch.exp(0.5 * logv)

        z = torch.randn([bsz, self.zdim], device=self.device)
        z = z * std + mean

        # DECODER
        hidden = self.latent2hidden(z)

        if self.bi_enc or self.nlayers > 1:
            # unflatten hidden state
            hidden = hidden.view(self.nlayers, bsz, self.hdim*self.ndirections)
        else:
            hidden = hidden.unsqueeze(0)

        return hidden, mean, logv, z

    def teacher_forcing_decode(self, inp, dec_h, z):
        bsz, seqlen = inp.size()
        out_emb = F.dropout(self.dec_emb(inp), p=self.dropout)
        z = z.unsqueeze(1).repeat([1, seqlen, 1])
        rnn_inp = torch.cat([out_emb, z], dim=2)
        # decoder forward pass
        outputs, _ = self.dec_rnn(rnn_inp, dec_h)
        logits = self.outlayer(F.dropout(outputs.contiguous().view(bsz*seqlen, -1), p=self.dropout)).contiguous().view(bsz, seqlen, -1)
        return logits, dec_h[0]

    def forward(self, inp):
        bsz, seqlen = inp.size()
        hidden, mean, logv, z = self.encode(inp)
        # init dec_h
        c = torch.zeros_like(hidden)
        dec_h = (hidden, c)
        # tf decoding
        logits_tf, dec_h_tf = self.teacher_forcing_decode(inp, dec_h, z)
        return logits_tf, mean, logv
```

Data pipeline using torchtext

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0")

go_token='<go>'
eos_token='<eos>'
pad_token='<pad>'
unk_token='<unk>'
tokenize=str.split

vectors=GloVe(name='6B', dim=50)

src = trg = torchtext.data.Field(sequential=True, use_vocab=True, init_token=go_token, 
                 eos_token=eos_token, fix_length=None, dtype=torch.long, 
                 preprocessing=None, postprocessing=None, lower=True, 
                 tokenize=tokenize, include_lengths=True, batch_first=True, 
                 pad_token=pad_token, unk_token=unk_token, pad_first=False, truncate_first=False)

train_ds = torchtext.datasets.TranslationDataset(
                            path='data/train', exts=('.txt', '.txt'),
                            fields=(src, trg))

src.build_vocab(train_ds, max_size=None, vectors=vectors)

vsz = len(src.vocab)
eos_idx = src.vocab.stoi[eos_token]
go_idx = src.vocab.stoi[go_token]
unk_idx = src.vocab.stoi[unk_token]
pad_idx = src.vocab.stoi[pad_token]

bsz = 100
train_iter = torchtext.data.BucketIterator(dataset=train_ds, batch_size=bsz,
                                            sort=True, sort_within_batch=True, repeat=True,
                                            sort_key=lambda x: len(x.src), device=device)
```

Instantiating a model

```
edim = 50
hdim = 96
dropout = .2
zdim = 32
nlayers = 1
bi_enc = True
vocab = TEXT.vocab
model = RVAE(vsz, edim, hdim, dropout, zdim, nlayers, bi_enc, go_idx, eos_idx, pad_idx, unk_idx, vocab, vectors.vectors, device)
```

Weight anealing function

```
def kl_anneal_function(x0, k, step, anneal_function):
    if anneal_function == 'logistic':
        return float(1/(1+np.exp(-k*(step-x0))))
    elif anneal_function == 'linear':
        return min(1, step/x0)

x0=8500*10
anneal_function = 'linear'
nepochs = 100
```

My training loop

```
for epoch in range(train_iter.epoch, nepochs):
    ep_st = time.time()
    epoch_loss_tf = 0
    epoch_loss_kl = 0
    for i, batch in enumerate(train_iter):
        model.zero_grad()

        src_b, lengths = batch.src
        inp = src_b[:, :-1]
        tgt = src_b[:, 1:].contiguous().view(-1)
        bsz, seqlen = inp.size()
        # forward
        logits_tf, mean, logv = model(inp)

        # loss calculation
        loss_tf = F.cross_entropy(logits_tf.view(bsz*seqlen, -1), tgt, ignore_index=pad_idx)
        kl_weight = kl_anneal_function(x0, k, train_iter.iterations, anneal_function)
        loss_kl = torch.mean(kl_weight *(-0.5 * torch.sum(1 + logv - mean.pow(2) - logv.exp())))
        loss = loss_tf + loss_kl
        # backward
        loss.backward()
        # clip gradients
        clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), .25)
        # optimizer step
        optimizer.step()
        # track loss
        epoch_loss_tf += float(loss_tf.item())
        epoch_loss_kl += float(loss_kl.item())
        #end of epoch
        if train_iter.epoch > epoch:
            ep_et = time.time()
            #log
            print("End of epoch {} | time elapsed {:5.3f} | loss_tf {:5.3f} |"
                  " loss_kl {:5.3f} |  kl_weight {:5.3f} | LR {}".
                  format(epoch, (ep_et-ep_st)/60, epoch_loss_tf, epoch_loss_kl, kl_weight,
                         optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'])
                 )
            _, indices = F.softmax(logits_tf, dim=-1).max(-1)
            sentences = [' '.join(src.vocab.itos[idx] for idx in sent) for i, sent in enumerate(indices.detach().squeeze().cpu().numpy().astype(int))]
            print(sentences)
            break
        del loss, loss_tf, loss_kl, logits_tf, mean, logv, src_b, lengths, batch, inp, tgt
        with torch.cuda.device(0):
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```